# Increment data (MongoDB) on each click (Angular / Node) as a Facebook "like button" - not working

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I would like to add a "Like" button on my app but it doesn't work.
I didn't have any particular error message, just the 400(Bad Request).

This is what I did :

post.HTML

```
<button (click)="onStar(post._id,post.like)"> {{ post.like }} fans </button>
```

post.TS

```
onStar(id:string,like:number) {
    like ++
    this.postService.updateLike(id,like).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('ok')
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }
```

post.service.TS

```
  updateLike(id:string, like:number) {
    let url = `${this.uri}/like/${id}`;
    console.log(like + ' + ' + id)
    return this.http.put(url, like,  { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError(this.errorMgmt)
    )
  }
```

Node.JS controller :

```
exports.addLike = (req, res, next) => {
  Post.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { like , _id: req.params.id })
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Great!'}))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
}
```

Node.JS route :

```
router.put('/like/:id', stuffCtrl.addLike);
```

**Many thanks in advance for your help :)**
have a nice day !
Rachel

Comment: I think your `console.log` line in your Node.js controller is interfering, although I'm not quite sure. Can you try remove it and see if it works?

Comment: Your Mongoose `updateOne` is throwing an error. Are you sure the `id` you're passing exists?

Comment: Hi @WillAlexander I'm sure the id exists. It works when I update all the object. But I would like to update only one parameter (like).

Comment: Looking at it, you’re not actually updating the Post object. You may need to first findOne the Post to get the current number of likes, then in the callback, call updateOne and set the likes to likes + 1. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Thanks for your help @WillAlexander
Do you mean, something like this ? :

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.id, "like._id":req.body.like},
         {
           $set: {
                "like.$.value ": +1
            }
         },
         { new: true } /
        ).exec(function(error, post) {
            if(error) {
                return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Update failed!'});
            }

            return res.status(200).send(post);
        });
```

Comment: Without formatting it’s hard to tell, but I think you’ve got the idea. Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `console.log` is not a promise. Try commenting out or removing that line:

```
Post.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { like , _id: req.params.id })
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Great!'}))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
```